# how to convert json string to dataframe on spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to convert string variable below to dataframe on spark.

```
val jsonStr = "{ "metadata": { "key": 84896, "value": 54 }}"
```

I know how to create dataframe from json file.

```
sqlContext.read.json("file.json")
```

but I don't know how to create dataframe from string variable.

How can I convert json String variable to dataframe.

Comment: val df = spark.read.json(spark.createDataset(jsonStr :: Nil))

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For [Spark 2.2+](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets):

```
import spark.implicits._
val jsonStr = """{ "metadata": { "key": 84896, "value": 54 }}"""
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)
```

For [Spark 2.1.x](https://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/):

```
val events = sc.parallelize("""{"action":"create","timestamp":"2016-01-07T00:01:17Z"}""" :: Nil)    
val df = sqlContext.read.json(events)
```

> Hint: this is using `sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD: RDD[Stirng])` overload.
>   There is also `sqlContext.read.json(path: String)` where it reads a Json file directly.

For [older versions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets):

```
val jsonStr = """{ "metadata": { "key": 84896, "value": 54 }}"""
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonStr))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
```

Comment: Out of date, see below answer for Spark 2.2

Comment: Is there a solution for python?

Comment: @Rohan yeah, just remove the "val" keywords, and it's basically Python.

Comment: @Jean, how to convert a json string(not a json file) to a dataframe in Spark Java

Comment: @user1326784 The code above is doing exactly that: `jsonStr` is a json string.

Comment: @devinbost Seq is also not Python.

Comment: For 2.2+ for python what is Seq ? how import ?

Answer (score 17):

> Since the function for reading JSON from an RDD got deprecated in
>   Spark 2.2, this would be another option:

```
val jsonStr = """{ "metadata": { "key": 84896, "value": 54 }}"""
import spark.implicits._ // spark is your SparkSession object
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example how to convert Json string to Dataframe in Java (Spark 2.2+):

```
String str1 = "{\"_id\":\"123\",\"ITEM\":\"Item 1\",\"CUSTOMER\":\"Billy\",\"AMOUNT\":285.2}";
String str2 = "{\"_id\":\"124\",\"ITEM\":\"Item 2\",\"CUSTOMER\":\"Sam\",\"AMOUNT\":245.85}";
List<String> jsonList = new ArrayList<>();
jsonList.add(str1);
jsonList.add(str2);
SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("myApp").setMaster("local"));
JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkContext);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
JavaRDD<String> javaRdd = javaSparkContext.parallelize(jsonList);
Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext.read().json(javaRdd);
data.show();
```

Here is the result:

```
+------+--------+------+---+
|AMOUNT|CUSTOMER|  ITEM|_id|
+------+--------+------+---+
| 285.2|   Billy|Item 1|123|
|245.85|     Sam|Item 2|124|
+------+--------+------+---+
```

Answer (score 4):

```
simple_json = '{"results":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"name"},{"a":2,"b":5,"c":"foo"}]}'
rddjson = sc.parallelize([simple_json])
df = sqlContext.read.json(rddjson)
```

The reference to the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399359/2187751

Answer (score 3):

To convert list of json Strings into DataFrame in Spark 2.2 =>

```
val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .master("local")
          .appName("Test")
          .getOrCreate()

var strList = List.empty[String]
var jsonString1 = """{"ID" : "111","NAME":"Arkay","LOC":"Pune"}"""
var jsonString2 = """{"ID" : "222","NAME":"DineshS","LOC":"PCMC"}"""
strList = strList :+ jsonString1
strList = strList :+ jsonString2

val rddData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(strList)
resultDF = spark.read.json(rddData)
resultDF.show()
```

Result:

```
+---+----+-------+
| ID| LOC|   NAME|
+---+----+-------+
|111|Pune|  Arkay|
|222|PCMC|DineshS|
+---+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

you can now directly read json from Dataset[String]: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html

```
val otherPeopleDataset = spark.createDataset(
  """{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}""" :: Nil)
val otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleDataset)
otherPeople.show()
// +---------------+----+
// |        address|name|
// +---------------+----+
// |[Columbus,Ohio]| Yin|
// +---------------+----+
```

Comment: how is do for python ?

Answer (score 2):

There will be some error in some case like Illegal Patter component : XXX so for that you need to add .option with timestamp in spark.read so updated code will be.

```
val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .master("local")
          .appName("Test")
          .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val jsonStr = """{ "metadata": { "key": 84896, "value": 54 }}"""
val df = spark.read.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ").json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val jsonStr = """{ "metadata": { "key": 84896, "value": 54 }}"""

val df = spark.read.json(spark.createDataset(jsonStr :: Nil)) 

display(df.withColumn("key",$"metadata.key").withColumn("value",$"metadata.value"))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply