# How to read in-memory JSON string into Spark DataFrame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read an in-memory JSON **string** into a Spark DataFrame on the fly:

```
var someJSON : String = getJSONSomehow()
val someDF : DataFrame = magic.convert(someJSON)
```

I've spent quite a bit of time looking at the Spark API, and the best I can find is to use a `sqlContext` like so:

```
var someJSON : String = getJSONSomehow()
val tmpFile : Output = Resource
    .fromFile(s"/tmp/json/${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}")
tmpFile.write("hello")(Codec.UTF8)
val someDF : DataFrame = sqlContext.read().json(tmpFile)
```

But this feels kind of awkward/wonky and imposes the following constraints:

1. It requires me to format my JSON to one object per line ([per documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(java.lang.String))); and
2. It forces me to write the JSON to a temp file, which is slow and awkward; and
3. It forces me to clean up temp files over time, which is cumbersome and feels "wrong" to me

So I ask: **Is there a direct and more efficient way to convert a JSON string into a Spark DataFrame?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert json string to dataframe on spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Spark SQL guide:

```
val otherPeopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(
"""{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}""" :: Nil)
val otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD)
otherPeople.show()
```

This creates a DataFrame from an intermediate RDD (created by passing a String).

Comment: The very good thing is, you can use it to filter wrong line before parsing (using ``sqlContext.read.json(sc.textFile("...").filter(....))``)