# Spark createDataFrame failing with ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm pretty new to Spark and am having a problem converting an RDD to a DataFrame. What I'm trying to do is take a log file, convert it to JSON using an existing jar (returns a string), and then make that resulting json into a dataframe. Here is what I have so far:

```
val serverLog = sc.textFile("/Users/Downloads/file1.log")
val jsonRows = serverLog.mapPartitions(partition => {
  val txfm = new JsonParser //*jar to parse logs to json*//
  partition.map(line => {
    Row(txfm.parseLine(line))
  })
})
```

When I run a `take(2)` on this I get something like:

```
[{"pwh":"600","sVe":"10.0","psh":"667","udt":"mobile"}]
[{"pwh":"800","sVe":"10.0","psh":"1000","udt":"desktop"}]
```

My problem comes here. I create a schema and try to create the df

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("pwh",StringType,true),
  StructField("sVe",StringType,true),...))

val jsonDf = sqlSession.createDataFrame(jsonRows, schema)
```

And the returned error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, pwh), StringType), true) AS _pwh#0
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, pwh), StringType), true)
:- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
:  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
:  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
:  +- 0
:- null
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Most of the SO answers I've found say I can use either `createDataFrame` or `toDF()`, but I've had no luck with either. I also tried converting the RDD to a `JavaRDD`, but that also did not work. Appreciate any insight you can give.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible example? Have you tried to not specify the schema and let it be inferred? `session.read.json(...)`

Comment: Are you sure you need an `Array` in schema? Wouldn't be schema rather per row?

Comment: @MirMasej `StructType` requires an array of `StructFields`, removing the array results in a compilation error.

Comment: Right, it needs be some kind of collection. The message is somewhat cryptic. Are you sure all the data will get `pwh` and `sVe` fields after parsing?

Comment: No, all of the keys have the potential to be absent. I was hoping that `nullable=true` would suffice for this

Comment: Generally we get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error when there is mismatch between structure of the schema and actual dataset. Just verify the no of columns in `jsonRows` and `schema`.

Comment: You can also directly convert a json RDD to dataframe using `val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)`. For reference see the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark

Comment: What is the return type of `txfm.parseLine(line)` ?

Comment: I found a few problems with my code. First, @RajatMishra - you were partly right. The JAR was returning a java `null` but Spark/Scala didn't seem to see that as equal to `nil` so it just totally died.
Additionally, I changed from a `mapPartitions` to just a `map` and that fixed the rest of the issues. But it is extremely inefficient, so I'd like to go back to the `mapPartitions`. I will update my code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

your defined schema is for RDD like:

```
{"pwh":"600","sVe":"10.0","psh":"667","udt":"mobile"}
{"pwh":"800","sVe":"10.0","psh":"1000","udt":"desktop"}
```

if you can change your RDD to make data as

```
{"logs": [{"pwh":"600","sVe":"10.0","psh":"667","udt":"mobile"}]}
```

an use this schema:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("logs",ArrayType( StructType(Seq(
    StructField("pwh",StringType,true),
    StructField("sVe",StringType,true), ...))
  ))
))

sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(jsonRows)
```