# How do you convert a JSON cell value to a Dataframe with PySpark?

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark

I'm working on a problem where my buddy saved some stuff into MySQL as JSON. When I convert it over to PySpark, some of the data appears like this....

```
threshold_df.show()

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|                   Value                |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| {"SHIRTS":{"threshold":"10","active":0}|
|"PANTS":{"threshold":"4","active":1},   |
|"SOCKS":{"threshold":2,"active":1},     |
|"SHOES":{"threshold":5,"active":0}}     |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Here is what I want...

```
       | threshold | active |
-----------------------------
SHIRTS |   10      |    0   |
-----------------------------
PANTS  |   04      |    1   |
-----------------------------
SOCKS  |   02      |    1   |
-----------------------------
SHOES  |   05      |    0   |
-----------------------------
```

How do I get there and thank you!

Comment: Can you add the code where you load the dataframe?

Comment: Hey sure! I actually am taking this from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Without a preview code showing how you are loading the data is kinda hard. But maybe this answer may help you: [Read JSON file as Pyspark Dataframe using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399245/read-json-file-as-pyspark-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the note. I actually think I found a work around that helped me. Basically did a JSON_EXTRACT() in MySQL 1st THEN I sent the data over to pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You'll need to fix it in SQL first. Since I'm in MySQL, I used JSON_EXTRACT ([Explained Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#title)). Here is the MySQL Work I did.

---

SELECT
product_type,
JSON_EXTRACT(datastuff,'$.value') as theshold_limit,
JSON_EXTRACT(datastuff,'$.active') as active_status
FROM
(select
'SHIRT' as product_type,
JSON_EXTRACT(value,'$.SHIRT') as datastuff
from storeschema.crm_configuration where code = 'CATEGORY_THRESHOLD') a1

```
UNION ALL
```

SELECT
product_type,
JSON_EXTRACT(datastuff,'$.value') as theshold_limit,
JSON_EXTRACT(datastuff,'$.active') as active_status
FROM
(select
'PANT' as product_type,
JSON_EXTRACT(value,'$.PANT') as datastuff
from storeschema.crm_configuration where code = 'CATEGORY_THRESHOLD') a2

---

After I brought in the storeschema.crm_configuration table, turned it into a DF ... then selectExpr('Above SQL') individually... then added a union.