# Getting keys and values from the rows of an RDD of stringified json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, rdd

Each row of my RDD looks somewhat like this:

```
[{"date":1.533204038E12,"time":1.533204038E12,"num":"KD10617029","type":"item","vat":0}]
```

My function:

```
def writeToES(data: java.util.List[String]): Unit = {

    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ESWriter").setMaster("local")
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sql: SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val spark: SparkSession = sql.sparkSession
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.implicits._

    val dataList = data.toArray()
    //println("datalist size: "+dataList.size)
    val dataDF = sc.parallelize(dataList)
              .map(x=>x.toString)
              .map(x=>x.split(","))
              .map(x=>Row.fromSeq(x))
              .map(x=>x.mkString(",")).toDF()
    dataDF.show()
    dataDF.take(1).toList.foreach(println)
    println(dataDF.take(1).length)
}
```

How do I get the "keys" from the stringified json in a list...
and how do i get the values of each json as a row in an rdd (or dataframe)

Comment: You can convert the string directly into a dataframe. Look at some of the answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user238607 suggested you can convert the string directly. But you can also use your intermediate RDD (with json string) directly:

```
val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Array("{\"date\":1.533204038E12,\"time\":1.533204038E12,\"num\":\"KD10617029\",\"type\":\"item\",\"vat\":0}"))
val dataframe = sparkSession.read.json(rdd).toDF
dataframe.show()
```

This creates a DataFrame from an intermediate RDD.

```
+--------------+----------+--------------+----+---+
|          date|       num|          time|type|vat|
+--------------+----------+--------------+----+---+
|1.533204038E12|KD10617029|1.533204038E12|item|  0|
+--------------+----------+--------------+----+---+
```

For Spark >= 2.2.0 use Dataset instead of RDD for json() function.