# Drop duplicate attribute in json parsing in spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jsonparser

I am parsing json file and I have one attribute which is coming for twice. So I want to drop one the attribute and so I can avoid ambiguous error. Here is the sample json. For example, address1 and Address1 has same value but only difference is first char is Capital letter. So I want to remove one of them from the json parsing in spark scala.

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "case": "12",
    "addresses": {
        "": [{
            "address1": "abc",
            "address2": "bkc",
            "Address1": "abc",
            "Address2": "bk"
        }, {
            "address1": "ede",
            "address2": "ak",
            "Address1": "ede",
            "Address2": "ak"
        }]
    },
    "FirstName": "abc",
    "LastName": "cvv"
}
```

Could some one guide me how to remove one of them while we are doing json parsing in spark scala. I need to automate this that means now we are facing issue with address and in future some other attributes may be similar issue. So instead of hard coding it, we may need to look for the solution for all the cases where we are facing similar issue.

Comment: are you sure that this is a valid schema? The name of the array is empty `""` this is not a valid property name in json syntax. You can try to parse the given json with spark as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark. Spark will ignore it since a empty name is not allowed

Comment: Hi Alexandros, The array name is addresses. I didn't put complete json which I am receiving. I just provided sample attributes how I am receiving the attribute name as "address1" and "Address1" and so I want to drop one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val jsonString = """
{
    "ID": 1,
    "case": "12",
    "addresses": [{
    "address1": "abc",
    "address2": "bkc",
    "Address1": "abc",
    "Address2": "bk"
    }, {
    "address1": "ede",
    "address2": "ak",
    "Address1": "ede",
    "Address2": "ak"
    }],
    "FirstName": "abc",
    "LastName": "cvv"
}
"""
val jsonDF = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//Add this before using drop
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")

jsonDF.withColumn("Addresses", explode(col("addresses")))
  .selectExpr("Addresses.*", "ID","case","FirstName","LastName")
  .drop("address1","address2")
  .show()
```

Comment: to make it generic, please pass the columns you want to remove to the drop method