# Best way of saving JSON data from Google Analytics into relational DB

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-analytics-api, rdbms

I'm looking for the most effective way of parallel loading Google Analytics data, which is represented in JSON files with nested objects structure, into Relational Database, in order to collect and analyze this statistics later.

I've found pandas.io.json.json_normalize which can flatten nested data into flat structure, also there is a pyspark solution with converting json to dataframe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark), but not sure about performance issues.

Can you describe best ways of loading data from Google Analytics API into RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer can be best answered when we have more context about what data you want to consume and how you'll be consuming them. For example, if you would be consuming only few of the all fields available - then it make sense to store only those, or if you'll be using some specific field as index then maybe we can index that field also.

One thing that I can recall from on top my head is `JSON type of Postgres`, as it's inbuilt and have several helper methods to do operation later on.

**References :**

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-json.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html

If you can update here what decision you take - it would be great to know.

Comment: Mohammad, thank you for your answer. I have to load all the avaliable data from Google Analytics, and store it into flat tables (visitors/hits/trafficsources/devices/...) so analysts could do their job based on this data. I don't want to save JSON directly in database, and look for a fastest way of transforming comples json objects into flat structure.