# Json string should be consumed as Kafka topic without schema in spark structured streaming

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I need to consume Kafka topic, which produces Dynamic Json string for each row.I cant parse the Json string without schema. In my case, Schema can be dynamic.
**spark.read.json** can infer json schema.But it requires either "DATASET" or "JSON file".

Any way to convert the Kafka topic(value) to DATASET? So that i can use **spark.read.json**, which accept DATASET as input and it can parse the schema of json.

But If i use below code.

```
val klines = spark.
  readStream.
  format("kafka").
  option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2").
  option("subscribe", "topic").
  load().
  select($"value".cast("string").alias("value"))

val query = klines.
  select(from_json($"value",schema=spark.read.json(klines.as[String]).schema)).
  writeStream.
  format("console").
  start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Getting below error:
***Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka***

I'm doing few intermediate calculations like flattening the schema. But if i do so same error occurs. How i can handle basic intermediate calculations in spark structured streaming(scala)?

Comment: Are you using spark streaming or spark structured streaming? If you're not using schema then where will you load those data?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Spark-structured streaming. It can be complex nested schema. Will flatten the schema, and find the schema in run time before loading..

Comment: @JavaTechnical:I cant change the Kafka output(select($"value".cast( to ="string").alias(alias = "value"))) to Seq. Any workaround pls?

Comment: @Raja You can always de-serialize the message to String (using StringDeserializer in Kafka consumer) and then the value you will get will be string, which you can eventually parse. So you don't need to cast to String, just put the `value.deserializer` to `StringDeserializer` and parse it

Comment: @JavaTechnical: Any example to start in scala? Im completely new to scala.

Comment: You tagged the wrong person ;)

Comment: @JavaTechnical Spark Structured Streaming *always* consumes as bytes. You cannot override deserializer configs, and it must be done in a Spark UDF

Comment: "completely new to scala" ... You could use Java or Python as well, but have you read the Kafka examples in Spark's Github repo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a string. You can just a schema of string type.

> So that i can use spark.read.json

`spark.read.json` is from **the filesystem**.

You probably want `spark.readStream.format("kafka")` if you want to read from Kafka, which is described in the Spark documentation in enough detail

First example in Spark documentation does exactly that

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

You will have issues doing any type of useful analysis of the data, however given that each record has the potential to not share the same fields, so doing something like `get_json_object` would be pointless

**You would argulably be better off using raw Kafka consumer API or KStreams**, which do not require any schema, however your issue is **not** schemas -- it is *deserialization* to an Object type with concrete fields that can be queried

Comment: I need to infer the json string dynamically without schema from kafka topic.Source schema tend to change.That's my objective. Only way is to use "spark.read.json". But i cant. Im also doing some intermediate calcuations like fattening the schema. Ending up with following error."Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka"

Comment: I feel like you didn't read what I wrote. And there is no way for Spark to use dynamic schemas in SparkSQL. You need to use Spark Streaming, NOT Spark **Structured** Streaming. **OR** you can use plain, vanilla Kafka consumer

Comment: Used Spark streaming to infer dynamic json. It works. Thanks

Comment: But while using spark streaming..code reacts abnormally in huge volume.I have used stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {val jsonDfall = spark.read.json(rdd)...each rdd has multiple records with different schema...i want to infer it on record level..

Comment: I'm not sure how `spark.read.json(rdd)` works because I thought that method can only read file paths, not RDD

Comment: Okay, well, if each record in the RDD has completely different data, I'm not sure what you're expecting to get... Like I said, using `get_json_object` function should probably be used instead at a per-record level

Comment: All the events will be captured in hbase..irrespective of the schema.Since Hbase can hold dynamic columns.

Comment: I'm not sure that is true... HBase is a columnar table, and Column families must be pre-defined... If you really wanted to store arbitrary JSON data, you'd use a document database such as Firebase, Mongo, or Couchbase.