# Nested JSON to dataframe in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I am using Spark/Scala to make an API Request and parse the response into a dataframe. Following is the sample JSON response I am using for testing purpose:

[API Request/Response](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getallmakes?format=json)

However, I tried to use the following [answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark) to convert to JSON but the nested fields are not being processed. Is there any way to convert the JSON string to a dataframe with columns??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the json that you have attached, if we read it as a df, it is giving a single row(and it is very huge) and hence spark might be truncating the result.
If this is what you want then you can try to use the spark property `spark.debug.maxToStringFields` to a higher value(default is 25)

`spark.conf().set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 100)`

However, if you want to process the `Results` from json, then it would be better to get it as data frame and then do the processing. Here is how you can do it

```
  val results = JsonParser.parseString(<json content>).getAsJsonObject().get("Results").getAsJsonArray.toString

  import spark.implicits._
  val df = spark.read.json(Seq(results).toDS)

  df.show(false)
```