# How can i convert JSON string RDD to structured data frame in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have text data and after applying some logic i change it in RDD as JSON data. I want to convert it into a structured data frame. Data is dynamic, so I can't create a static schema for columns. One way which I tried is to write RDD in a temporary location and then read it as json. This creates a structured output for me.

```
val tempPath:String = "some temp path"
rdd.saveAsTextFile(tempPath)
sparkSession.read.json(tempPath)
```

I want to avoid writing data in a temporary location. Is there any way I can read this json string RDD as structured data without writing it in a temporary location?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271611/how-to-convert-json-string-to-dataframe-on-spark), you can do:

```scala
val tempPath: String = "some temp path"

val dataset = spark.read.json(Seq(tempPath).toDS)
```

Don't forget to:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Otherwise `toDS` will not be recognized. Good luck!

Comment: I tried this approach and worked fine, but i see a performance issue. For 5.5 million records set, with same infrastructure,
1. writing on temp location and reading as json took 22 - 23 minutes
2. converting RDD in DataSet and reading as json took more than 40 minutes.
     import sparkSession.implicits._
    sparkSession.read.json(rdd.toDS())

Comment: If you are using dataframes, you might want to create a new column and have that string as literal, or you can also use `sparkContext.parallelize` to get that straight into RDD. Performance will be quite dependent on your use case as well, so it's hard to tell